# How to check whether or not your GPU is currently using Mesa for rendering OpenGL/Vulkan?

Tags: linux, hardware, intel, opengl, mesa

As a Linux fan, I want to get into OpenGL development as a hobby of mine.

I know that OpenGL is just an API that the GPU vendors must implement.

Some GPU vendors' OpenGL/Vulkan implementations are proprietary, whilst some are open source (like Intel).

Because I like open source, I want to make sure I don't use anything proprietary when I develop stuff, so how would I go about checking whether or not my GPU is currently using Mesa for rendering?

The reason I am asking is because I've gotten mixed messages online, as I have heard that you can apparently still have Mesa installed but the GPU will be using something else that is proprietary, which is why I wanted to ask this question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Run this in your terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep -i mesa
```

If you do see something in the output, then you should be using mesa. If nothing shows up, it's something else.

And if it's something else, `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` should tell you what it is.

---

### Full explanation:

So first of all, it's not really about choosing which OpenGL/Vulkan implementation. The implementation you use depends on which GPU driver you use. So what you really wanna do is to ensure that you are using a GPU driver that Mesa supports.

With that said, there are not many options of GPU drivers anyway. If you are using Intel or AMD, you are most likely already using the open source drivers that work with Mesa. There's simply no other options for Intel, and the proprietary driver of AMD had been deprecated.

If you are using Nvidia, it's a little bit more complicated. As of now, there are three drivers out there - the official and proprietary Nvidia driver, the open-source version of the official Nvidia driver, and nouveau.

- The first offers the best performance, but, as I said, it's proprietary, and it provides its own proprietary implementation of OpenGL. You can't use mesa with it.
- The second was a very new thing that was released May this year. It is the open-sourced version of their proprietary driver. It also has it's own implementation of OpenGL, which is not Mesa. But it IS open-source, and offers comparable performance as the proprietary one.
- The last one, nouveau, is the old open-source driver for Nvidia that was written by the community through reverse-engineering the proprietary Nvidia driver. This used to be the only option if you really want to use open-source driver with Nvidia's GPU, and it does work with Mesa. And since it's based on reverse-engineering, the performance sucks.

So, in conclusion, if you happened to be on Nvidia's GPU, and HAVE TO USE MESA, you could go with nouveau, though I do not recommend that due to its poor performance. If you are just looking for being open-source, install the open-source version of the official Nvidia driver. (Remember to uninstall every other driver and only install the driver you want to use.)

---

However, with all that being said, one thing should be clarified.

> I want to make sure I don't use anything proprietary when I develop stuff

Are you actually trying to make sure that "you, yourself, when developing and/or using your computer, are not using anything proprietary", or it's just "nothing in the software that you developed would use proprietary stuff"?

If it's the later case, you don't even need to care about which driver or implementation you are using. They are all OpenGL anyways, and since OpenGL itself is open, you are not using anything proprietary in your own code. If it's the former case, then, as I've said, just install the correct driver and you should be good.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Just to clarify (apologies for the bad wording), I meant the second option, I want everything to be 100% open source even at the lowest of levels. E.g. I cannot use an API that may have an implementation that is proprietary, even if the API is open in itself. Pleasantly surprised I am using Mesa :D